# How to Redeclare 0 Variable at Start of New Dimensional Loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My array is being generated by [compromise js](http://compromise.cool/), turned into a JSON variable using `var json = JSON.stringify(tags);` brought over in an AJAX call `data:{json:json}` to a `POST` method `PHP` file `ajax.php`.

Here's what `ajax.php` looks like

```
$json = $_POST['json'];

$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

And the `$data` coming over...

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

. . .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => the
            [normal] => the
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Determiner
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => quick
            [normal] => quick
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Comparable
                    [1] => Adjective
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => brown
            [normal] => brown
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Comparable
                    [1] => Adjective
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => fox
            [normal] => fox
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Noun
                    [1] => Singular
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => jumped
            [normal] => jumped
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PastTense
                    [1] => Verb
                    [2] => VerbPhrase
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => over
            [normal] => over
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Adjective
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [text] => the
            [normal] => the
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Determiner
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [text] => lazy
            [normal] => lazy
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Adjective
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [text] => dog
            [normal] => dog
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Noun
                    [1] => Singular
                )

        )

)
```

Here's what I want the array to look like..

> Expected Result

```
Array
(
    [the] => Array
        (
            [0] => Determiner
        )

    [quick] => Array
        (
            [0] => Comparable
            [1] => Adjective
        )

    [brown] => Array
        (
            [0] => Comparable
            [1] => Adjective
        )

    [fox] => Array
        (
            [0] => Noun
            [1] => Singular
        )
)
```

And my attempted method at doing so:

```
$tags = array();
$x = 0;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $tags[$value['normal']] = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($value['tags']);$i++) {
    $tags[$x] = $value['tags'][$i];
    $x++;
}
}
```

This outputs an array similar to what I want, but the index `$x` is auto-incrementing at the start of the array instead of at each new array within the array.

```
Array
(
    [the] => Array
        (
        )

    [0] => Determiner
    [quick] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Comparable
    [2] => Adjective
    [brown] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Comparable
    [4] => Adjective
    [fox] => Array
        (
        )

    [5] => Noun
    [6] => Singular
    [jumped] => Array
        (
        )

    [7] => PastTense
    [8] => Verb
    [9] => VerbPhrase
    [over] => Array
        (
        )

    [10] => Adjective
    [11] => Determiner
    [lazy] => Array
        (
        )

    [12] => Adjective
    [dog] => Array
        (
        )

    [13] => Noun
    [14] => Singular
)
```

Anything other than this, putting `$x` into different places at the beginning and end of the `foreach` loop, I tried using `array_values($tags[$value['normal']]);` at the end of the `foreach` loop at the beginning of the `for` loop, trying it with $i in the for loop

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($value['tags']);$i++) {
    $tags[$i] = $value['tags'][$i];
}
```

Just causes mayhem in the array

```
Array
(
    [the] => Array
        (
        )

    [0] => Noun
    [quick] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Singular
    [brown] => Array
        (
        )

    [fox] => Array
        (
        )

    [jumped] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => VerbPhrase
    [over] => Array
        (
        )

    [lazy] => Array
        (
        )

    [dog] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve my Expected Result above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php) with an [array union operation](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.array.php) ...

```
$tags = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + [$item['normal'] => $item['tags']];
}, []);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/992451

---

One thing to keep in mind is that you have not specified what should happen with duplicate entries (for example *"the"*). The array union operator will favour the first entry and discard the others. This is fine with your example because each duplicate word has identical tags but if not, you might want to come up with a strategy for merging the `tags` content.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking and looking into that. Is there a way with array_reduce (never heard of it by the way, outputs exactly how I wanted), to add indexes to the array? meaning instead of `Array ( [key]` and getting into the key, something like `Array
( [0] => Array (  [key] => Array` . . .

Comment: @BrianBruman not sure what you mean. If the desired output in your question is not actually what you want, then why is it in your question?

Comment: I was not thinking about duplicate keys yet just trying to figure out how to construct the array

Comment: I will accept your answer as you had a very clean method for my Expected Output, but as for the duplicate key issue @Schien deserves an accepted answer as well

Comment: @BrianBruman you have not specified at all what should happen with duplicate entries so how can anyone get that correct?

Comment: I've already accepted your answer and no one else's. I realize I had an error in the foreward thinking of the code, but as I explained the thought had not crossed my mind at the time of writing. I'm not sure how else you'd like me to respond.

Comment: @BrianBruman If one of the other answers provides the solution you actually want, you can always change your _"accept"_ selection. You can also edit your question if your requirements differ to what you've written

Comment: What I'd really like to know is if there is a tool for manually constructing arrays in your `eval.in` demo (aka `$data`). I'd like to mess with arrays without having to go though the process of building them, but the process seems tedious. This is my actual question.

Answer (score 3):

A simple foreach loop might do what you like

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$result = []; // Initialize output array
foreach ($data as $array) {
    $result[] = array($array['text'] => $array['tags']);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ha! Actually, this should be the accepted answer :)! Output is perfect https://pastebin.com/pbb4y96F and code is so simple looking at it. Going to use this one

Comment: @BrianBruman but that isn't the _expected result_ from your question

Answer (score 2):

Your unexpected array has all the information you need for the expected array. So we can do some transformation:

```
$data=json_decode($json_data,true);

$terms=array();
foreach ($data as $rec){
  $text=$rec['text'];
  $tags=$rec['tags'];
  if (!is_array($terms[$text])) $terms[$text]=array();
  foreach ($tags as $tag) $terms[$text][$tag]=$tag;
}
```

Edit: instead of having [0]=>Tag 1, [1]=>Tag 2, ... the array now stores the tags in keys as well:

```
  [Tag 1]=>"Tag 1",
  [Tag 2]=>"Tag 2"
```

This is a simplistic way to avoid duplicates. If you really insist on getting a numeric index, you may use array_values during retrieval.

Comment: This will result in the duplicate entries (eg _"the"_) having multiple identical tags, eg `['Determiner', 'Determiner']`

Comment: I have edited the answer to avoid duplicates. This method is faster than calling in_array.

Comment: Interesting approach! Thank you, looking it over. I do get a Notice: `Undefined index: dog in C:\wamp64\www\N\ajax.php on line 11` (the `if (!is_array($terms[$text])) $terms[$text]=array();` line which I'm trying to figure out but it does output well

Comment: @BrianBruman that's because this fails to check that `$terms[$text]` exists before using it in `is_array()`